# How to split Number in googlesheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, lambda, split, sequence

Hello  I would like to ask how to split this number 122426122427122428122429122430122441 into six digit numbers and put it to rows in google sheets.

How is it possible do this?
Thank you

I tried split functions but i did not find any positions function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&""; "(.{6})"; "$1​"); "​"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `byrow()`, `sequence()` and `mid()`, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  sequence(len(A2) / 6, 1, 1, 6), 
  lambda( 
    start, 
    mid(A2, start, 6) 
  ) 
)
```